# How to merge this two exact event with different element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two element that when executed is doing same function. How to merge these script to make it more clean?

```
//e_jumlah script
$("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_jumlah',function(){             
    var par_jml = $(this).val().replace(/,/g , '');
    var par_hrg = $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_harga').val().replace(/,/g , '');

    var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_total').val(total.toLocaleString());
});

//e_harga script
$("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_harga',function(){              

    var par_hrg = $(this).val().replace(/,/g , '');
    var par_jml = $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_jumlah').val().replace(/,/g , '');

    var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_total').val(total.toLocaleString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a common class to both DOM and then invoke the function for that class. In that class, you could use the unique class (or id preferably) to get the values.

```js
$(".container").on('keyup','.input-item',function(){  
    var par_jml = $('.e_jumlah').val().replace(/,/g , '');
    var par_hrg = $('.e_harga').val().replace(/,/g , '');
    var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

   var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

    $('.total').val(total.toLocaleString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="input-item e_jumlah" id="s1" placeholder="input1" value="0">
  <input class="input-item e_harga" id="s1" placeholder="input1" value="0">
  <input class="total">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_jumlah , .e_harga ',function(event){             
    var par_jml = $(this).val().replace(/,/g , '');
```

// using event object try to get the class like event.target pass the respected class to the find method 
        var par_hrg = $(this).closest('tr').find(event).val().replace(/,/g , '');

```
    var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_total').val(total.toLocaleString());
});
```

You can pass multiple Selectors . http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: find('.e_harga') this selector is different between two element  it have to be dynamic so this solution will not work

Comment: You can check it by adding a variable hasEJumlah =  $(this).hasClass("e_jumlah"); & set the value accordingly

Comment: event is an object contains event data can't be used .find(event) for find element selector in side tr

Comment: using event object he can get the class and he can pass the respected class to the find method  @AhmedYousif .. As a solution I just added the multiple selectors

Answer (score 0):

you can pass either e_harga or e_jumlah as an arg to the function like below:

```
function convertSrting(passAnArgument){ //.e_harga or .e_jumlah
$("#t_jps_item").on('keyup',passAnArgument,function(){             
    var par_jml = $(this).val().replace(/,/g , '');
    var par_hrg = $(this).closest('tr').find(passAnArgument).val().replace(/,/g , '');

    var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

    $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_total').val(total.toLocaleString());
});
}
```

The above functions acts as common function now

bind events for both elements

```
convertSrting('.e_harga')
convertSrting('.e_jumlah')
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of the input fields to one function where we define the body which is to be executed for both the elements.

```
function executeCode(e){
    var par_jml = $(e.currentTarget).val().replace(/,/g , '');
    var par_hrg = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').find('.e_harga').val().replace(/,/g , '');

    var total   = parseInt(par_jml) * parseFloat(par_hrg);

    $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').find('.e_total').val(total.toLocaleString());

}

$("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_jumlah',function(e){             
    executeCode(e)
});

//e_harga script
$("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_harga',function(e){              
    executeCode(e)    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use event data to  pass either `.e_harga` or `.e_jumlah` as an argument to the common event handler callback as following :

```
    $("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_jumlah',{classSelector: '.e_harga'},function(event){commonHandler(event);});
    $("#t_jps_item").on('keyup','.e_harga',{classSelector: '.e_jumlah'}, function(event){commonHandler(event);});

    function commonHandler(event){             
            var par = $(this).val().replace(/,/g , '');
            var par_hrg_Or_jml = $(this).closest('tr').find(event.data.classSelector).val().replace(/,/g , '');   
            var total   = parseInt(par) * parseFloat(par_hrg_Or_jml);   
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.e_total').val(total.toLocaleString());
}
```

this event handler callback is common between these two elements